# React 18 how to make functions pure?

Tags: reactjs

Im making a small hobby project. But now i ran into the problem of the strict mode. With each useEffect a state change is fired twice whitch increments value twice.

This is from one of the context providers

```
    const updateBuilding = (building: ProductionBuilding): ProductionBuilding => {
    let elapsedTime = building.elapsedTime + deltaTime;
    if(elapsedTime >= building.productionTime){
        console.log("here");
        addRawResource(RawResource.IRON, 1);
        elapsedTime = 0;
    }
    return {...building, elapsedTime};
};

useEffect(() => {
    if(productionBuildings.length > 0){
        setProductionBuildings((previousState) => {
            return previousState.map(updateBuilding);
        })
    }
}, [frameTime]);
```

And this is the another one that gets called

```
    const [rawResources, setRawResources] = useState<RawResources>({
    [RawResource.WATER]: 0,
    [RawResource.IRON]: 0,
    [RawResource.COPPER]: 0,
    [RawResource.WOOD]: 0
});

const addRawResource = (rawResource: RawResource, amount: number) => {
    setRawResources((prevValue) => {
        return {...prevValue, [rawResource]: prevValue[rawResource] + amount};
    })
};
```

frameTime is tied to the requestAnimationFrame so it keeps looping and rerendering the application at regular intervals. deltaTime is calculated from frameTime. I understand that react strictMode is there to help find these kind of bugs. But i cant seem to figure out how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: you want to render only once than twice ? that's what you are looking for ?

Comment: I want to increment the value only once. Right now, whenever the condition in updateBuilding  is met, the value gets incremented twice. It might well be the situation where is should turn off strict mode, but then again, it might be good to try it work out within strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

In **React 18** there is a new `development-only check to Strict Mode`. This new check will automatically **unmount and remount every component**, whenever a component mounts for the first time. According to [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state) this feature will give React better performance out-of-the-box.

to prevent this behavior **just turn off strict mode** but if you want to keep it for additional checks and warnings for its descendants. you can create a custom hook that can be used instead of `useEffect()` with no re-rendering.

**this is an example (with no typescript) :**

```
export const useEffectOnce = ( effect )=> {

  const destroyFunc = useRef();
  const effectCalled = useRef(false);
  const renderAfterCalled = useRef(false);
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  if (effectCalled.current) {
      renderAfterCalled.current = true;
  }

  useEffect( ()=> {

      // only execute the effect first time around
      if (!effectCalled.current) { 
        destroyFunc.current = effect();
        effectCalled.current = true;
      }

      // this forces one render after the effect is run
      setVal(val => val + 1);

      return ()=> {
        // if the comp didn't render since the useEffect was called,
        // we know it's the dummy React cycle
        if (!renderAfterCalled.current) { return; }
        if (destroyFunc.current) { destroyFunc.current(); }
      };
  }, []);
};
```

**same example (with typescript) :**

```
export const useEffectOnce = (effect: () => void | (() => void)) => {
  const destroyFunc = useRef<void | (() => void)>();
  const effectCalled = useRef(false);
  const renderAfterCalled = useRef(false);
  const [val, setVal] = useState<number>(0);

  if (effectCalled.current) {
    renderAfterCalled.current = true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // only execute the effect first time around
    if (!effectCalled.current) {
      destroyFunc.current = effect();
      effectCalled.current = true;
    }

    // this forces one render after the effect is run
    setVal((val) => val + 1);

    return () => {
      // if the comp didn't render since the useEffect was called,
      // we know it's the dummy React cycle
      if (!renderAfterCalled.current) {
        return;
      }
      if (destroyFunc.current) {
        destroyFunc.current();
      }
    };
  }, []);
};
```

**Note  :** before deploying just change this custom hook to the `useEffect hook` . useEffect runs twice only with strict mode in development but in production, it will not